# Indent JS in Android Studio

Tags: javascript, react-native, android-studio

I am setting up a react-native project with android studio. 
So i have react-native code in .js files. But Auto-indent is not working.

I have read a lot of similar questions here but found no answer.

More Info:

- Code -> Auto-indent Lines is not clickable.
- crtl+alt+L -> shows    "content is already properly formatted"
- crtl + shift + alt + L -> shows dialog, i can click "run" but it does not change anything
- i dont have IntelliJ ultimate
- settings -> editor -> code styles do not show JS
- installed JS Toolsbox Plugin -> did not find anything related in its settings
- could not find any other plugins in the marketplace

what am i missing?

Answer (score 0):

To have full compatibility with Js files using IntelliJ products, you should use IntelliJ ultimate.

VsCode is free and with a lot of extensions make it very good for react-native dev